# How to move time axis to the right side in Fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

If we set a dir property to `rtl`, then the time axis goes to the right side, I need the same, but the rest of the calendar should be in `ltr` mode. I tried swapping cells in the grid:

```
const timeElements = [].slice.call(slats.querySelectorAll('.fc-time'));

timeElements.forEach((item: HTMLElement) => {
    const parent = item.parentNode;
    if (parent) {
       parent.insertBefore(parent.children[1], parent.children[0]);
    }
});
```

But it breaks columns adjustment: 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAgcV.png)

Is there any way to do that without changing the source code?

Comment: You'd need to make your own [custom view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) (probably by cloning the timeGrid view and adjusting it). Not necessarily an easy job though. Consider whether you really need this small change before starting to work on it!

Comment: Well, that's what I am trying to avoid. But if there is no way to achieve that without tweaking the code, then I have no choice :)
@ADyson thanks for your reply!